# Can VIM autoindent SQL?

Tags: sql, vim, indentation, auto-indent

"[SQL Statement indentation good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272210/sql-statement-indentation-good-practice/272232#272232)" appears to be the accepted format for writing SQL blocks.

Is there a Vim indent/syntax file that would adhere to this standard, or at least be close?

Currently my Vim left alights pretty much everything and only indents certain keywords.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By installing the python module **sqlparse**, which makes the `sqlformat` command available in your terminal.

`pip install sqlparse`

from vim you can use

`:%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower -`

in order to attach a shortcut **,pt** I added following configuration to my `.vimrc` config file:

```
autocmd FileType sql call SqlFormatter()
augroup end
function SqlFormatter()
    set noai
    " set mappings...
    map ,pt  :%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower -<CR>
endfunction
```

You can customize sqlformat a bit. See

> sqlformat --help

Comment: I mapped \f to call _sqlformat_ by adding this one line to my _~/.vimrc_:
```map \f :%!sqlformat --reindent --indent_columns --keywords upper --identifiers lower -<CR>```

Comment: Mind that `autocmd FileType sql call SqlFormatter()` will make this work only in a sql file. If you want it to be called at the start of any file so that the shortcut is always available, use `nnoremap call SqlFormatter()` instead. This might be interesting if you have SQL strings embedded in another language. Since sqlformat works on a whole file, you need to use another formatter, see [Is there a way to let sqlformat change only a selection within a file in VIM?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/36643/is-there-a-way-to-let-sqlformat-or-another-sql-formatter-change-only-a-selection).

Answer (score 11):

"[SQLUtilities : SQL utilities - Formatting, generate - columns lists, procedures for databases](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=492)" has the SQL Utilities plugin, which is capable. And "[How to auto-format and auto-capitalize SQL in Vim](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69576/sql-auto-formatting-and-auto-capatilize-in-vim)" is a related discussion.

Answer (score 8):

If you use [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) then you can add the [coc-sql extension](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-sql).

Comment: This was the solution I went with... 

`:CocCommand` takes you to a fuzzy finder - 
Type in `sql.Format` and you're golden.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) plugin:

- Install `vim-autoformat` with your favourite plugin-manager (I prefer lightweight [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug))
- Install `sqlparse` with `pip`
- Add the following lines to your vim/nvim config

```
noremap <F3> :Autoformat<CR>
let g:formatdef_sql = '"sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper - identifiers lower -"'
let g:formatters_sql = ['sql']
```

If you see this message: `vim has no support for python`, you should rebuild your vim with python support or install [python-client](https://github.com/neovim/python-client) for neovim

Comment: Vim-autoformat now has support for sqlformat by default.

Answer (score 3):

Like Valerio's answer, I recommend using [sqlformat](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) albiet with Vim's builtin `formatprg`, which is `gq` by default.

```
setlocal formatprg=sqlformat\ --reindent\ --keywords\ upper\ --identifiers\ lower\ -
```

I have the line above under my `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim` file.

This allows you to use Vim's builtin `gq` against any selection, or against known Vim's objects within sql, or simply `gggqG` to reindent the entire buffer.