# VIM run command when opening .sql files

Tags: windows, vim, vim-plugin

I am having a hard time figuring this out.

I am trying to run the below command when i open a sql file in VIM.

```
 :%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers upper -
```

I know this is probably easy and i am over thinking it but have been attempting various variations of the below in my _vimrc file and no luck

```
autocmd FileType sql call SqlFormatter()
augroup end

  function SqlFormatter()
    set noai
    set mappings map ,pt  :%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers upper -<CR>
 endfunction
```

EDIT:
 when i run this inside VIM nothing happens

```
:call SqlFormatter()
```

when i run i can see the SqlFormatter() function in the list
    :function

Currently the function in my _vimrc file looks like and i am still having no luck

```
autocmd FileType sql call SqlFormatter()
augroup end
function SqlFormatter()
set noai
" set mappings...
map ,pt  :%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers lower -
endfunction
```

Comment: Looks like you're close; try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43635763/11384392)

Comment: That answer is where I started at, still unable to get it to auto format. I updated my question with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this down into components. First the mapping:

```
map ,pt :%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers upper -<cr>
```

The general rules with mappings is to supply a mode and use `noremap` if you are able. So this becomes:

```
nnoremap ,pt :%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers upper -<cr>
```

Next we need to understand buffer-local mappings. Your mapping is global which means once you open a buffer with a `'filetype'` of `sql` then this mapping will work in any buffer. This is not likely not what you want. By using the `<buffer>` option we can set this mapping for just this buffer.

You are using an `FileType` autocmd event to trigger this mapping for `sql` filetypes. Here is that cleaned up:

```
augroup SqlStuff
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType sql call SqlFormatter()
augroup end

function SqlFormatter()
    set noautoindent
    nnoremap <buffer> ,pt :%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers upper -<cr>
endfunction
```

Additionally, you may want to avoid the `autocmd` & function all together and just add both the setting and the mapping into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim`

```
set noautoindent
nnoremap <buffer> ,pt :%!sqlformat --reindent --keywords upper --identifiers upper -<cr>
```

Note: I have not tested this mapping so if there is an issue with `sqlformat` then that will also need to be fixed

For more help see:

```
:h :map-commands
:h :map-local
:h :autocmd
:h :augroup
:h FileType
:h after-directory
```

More help from [Learning Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/):

- [Basic Mapping](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/03.html)
- [Modal Mapping](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/04.html)
- [Strict Mapping](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html)
- [Buffer-Local Options and Mappings](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/11.html)
- [Autocommands](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html)
- [Autocommand Groups](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html)

Comment: If we’re going to ftplugin, might as well setlocal. If we keep the autocommand,  might as well remove the mapping and make it run the command. Either way +1

Comment: Thank you these links are what i needed