# How to disable caps lock when entering normal mode in VSCode Vim?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

## My environment

MacOS:

Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101)

VSCode:

Version: 1.45.1
Commit: 5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a
Date: 2020-05-14T08:33:47.663Z
Electron: 7.2.4
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.5.0

VSCode Vim:

v1.14.5

## Issue

Often times, when I press the caps lock key in insert mode or command mode, I forget to press it again to turn it off when we enter normal mode, and that can cause a lot of trouble.

So there is a solution for it for the regular vim that you use in a terminal.
https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Insert-mode_only_Caps_Lock

## Question

- Is there a way to use this "Insert-mode only Caps Lock" with VSCode Vim(extension)?
- Is there anyway I can turn off caps lock when I go back to normal mode from insert/command mode?
- Is there anyway I can turn off caps lock whenever Esc key is pressed (on MacOS)?
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61242/turn-off-caps-lock-when-escape-is-pressed
  (Maybe withe a help of a software like Karabiner Elements?)

## What I've tried that didn't work

- Since VSCode supports .`.vimrc`, I created it and put this code, but it didn't work. (This works with regular vim in the terminal)

```c
for c in range(char2nr('A'), char2nr('Z'))
  execute 'lnoremap ' . nr2char(c+32) . ' ' . nr2char(c)
  execute 'lnoremap ' . nr2char(c) . ' ' . nr2char(c+32)
endfor
autocmd InsertLeave * set iminsert=0
```

- I looked for a "Karabiner-Elements complex_modifications rules", but couldn't find what I was looking for.
  https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/

Comment: How about switching `Caps Lock` to `ESC` or `CTRL` and the `ESC` key to `Caps Lock`? I almost never need `Caps Lock`, so the 'far away' `ESC` key seems perfect for this :)

Comment: @okket I use vim for editing a lot of sql files and by style I choose uppercase sql. I run into this issue a lot... really just need to figure out a way to toggle capslock off when escape is pressed, while retaining normal capslock functionality in normal mode.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is a "toggle capslock" command or anything similar for vscode. I don't have a lot of experience in vscode bindings... perhaps there is an easy solution that we are missing here... See: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13312#issuecomment-753669065

Comment: Personally, I'd use an script or plugin that autoformats the SQL queries for me, see here for some good pointers for VIM https://stackoverflow.com/a/8577782/2955999. But I can understand the need for Caps Lock in general, e.g. when dealing with a lot of SQL outside of VIM.

Comment: Honestly at this point, I have forced myself to either use shift or explicitly remember to press turn capslock off before I escape to normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [sedleds](https://github.com/damieng/setledsmac) and an autocmd like

```
autocmd InsertLeavePre * !setleds\ -caps
```

*untested*

I tried with `import pyautogui ; pyautogui.press('CAPSLOCK')`  and that toggles the caps key, but I have not found a way how to detect if capslock is 'locked' or not. It would otherwise work with linux, windows and macos as it seems.