# Need help in writing Efficient SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I have the following query, written inside perl script:

```
        insert into #temp_table
        select distinct bv.port,bv.sip,avg(bv.bv) bv, isnull(avg(bv.book_sum),0) book_sum,
        avg(bv.book_tot) book_tot,
        check_null = case when bv.book_sum = null then 0 else 1 end         
        from table_bv bv, table_group pge, table_master sm
        where pge.a_p_g = '$val'
        and pge.p_c = bv.port
        and bv.r = '$r'
        and bv.effective_date = '$date'
        and sm.sip = bv.sip
```

query continued -- need help below (can some one help me make this efficient, or rewriting, I am thinking its wrong)

```
   and ((sm.s_g = 'FE')OR(sm.s_g='CH')OR(sm.s_g='FX')
   OR(sm.s_g='SH')OR(sm.s_g='FD')OR(sm.s_g='EY')
   OR ((sm.s_t = 'TA' OR sm.s_t='ON')))
```

query continued below

```
       group by bv.port,bv.sip
```

query ends

explanation: some $val that contain sip with 
s_g ('FE','CH','FX','SH','FD','EY') and 
s_t ('TA','ON') have book_sum as null. The temp_table does not take null values, 
hence I am inserting them as zero ( isnull(avg(bv.book_sum),0) ) where ever it encounters a null for the following s_g and s_m ONLY.

I have tried making the query as follows but it made my script to stop wroking:

```
and sm.s_g in ('FE', 'CH','FX','SH','FD','EY') 
or sm.s_t in ('TA','ON')`
```

Comment: So is your query broken, or inefficient? What is the problem?

Comment: its not broken since the query runs. but when I change it with the following it breaks  " and sm.s_g in ('FE', 'CH','FX','SH','FD','EY') 
or sm.s_t in ('TA','ON') "

Comment: What do you mean "it breaks"? What is the error message? People will not be able to help you if you are not concise.

Comment: Not related to performance, but a few tips: 1) Don't embed Perl variables in SQL; it's dangerous. Instead, use [placeholders](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values). 2) Capitalize SQL keywords to make your query easier to read, e.g. `SELECT column FROM table` 3) Use explicit `JOIN`s instead of the old-style `SELECT foo FROM table1, table2, table3 ...` since the intent is clearer. 4) Use indentation. There is no universally-accepted standard, but look at what [other people do](http://stackoverflow.com/q/272210/176646) to get an idea. Something is better than nothing.

Comment: This query is a part of a script which contains other queries as well. There is no error message the script gets stuck. So I think when I try to write it the following way "and sm.s_g in ('FE', 'CH','FX','SH','FD','EY') or sm.s_t in ('TA','ON') " it gets stuck.

Answer (score 2):

I know this should be a comment, but I don't have the rep.  To me, it looks like it's hanging because you lost your grouping at the end.  I think it should be:

```
and ( 
    sm.s_g in ('FE', 'CH','FX','SH','FD','EY') 
    or 
    sm.s_t in ('TA','ON')
)
```

Note the parentheses.  Otherwise, you're asking for all of the earlier conditions, OR that sm.s_t is one of TA or ON, which is a much larger set than you're anticipating, which may cause it to spin.