# SQL Select Query Fetching Very Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query fetching data very slow..I want to fast the query..

i.e. it will taking too much time while fetching data from database..
So I need a solution..

Here is my SQL Server query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ISNULL(V.VendorItemId, 0) AS VendorItemId, 
    ISNULL(V.VendorItemNumber, I.Ord_guide) AS VendorItemNumber,
    ISNULL(V.VendorItemDescription, I.Pkg_desc) AS VendorItemDescription,
    Id = (SELECT Min(k.Id) 
          FROM dbo.InvoiceImportDataPrice k 
          WHERE K.Ord_guide = I.Ord_guide 
            AND K.Price = I.Price
            AND k.Pkg_desc = I.Pkg_desc 
            AND k.Store_name = I.Store_name 
            AND k.InvoiceImportHistoryId = 128),
    I.InvoiceImportHistoryId, I.Price,
    ISNULL(V.CurrentPrice, 0) AS CurrentPrice,
    ISNULL(ISNULL(V.CurrentPrice, 0) - ISNULL(I.Price, 0), 0) AS differencePrice,
    I.Invoice_No, I.Sold_to, I.Store_name, I.Deliv_date,
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(I.Qty_ship, '0') = '0' THEN '-0' ELSE I.Qty_ship END) AS Qty_ship, 
    I.Ship_um, 
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(I.Qty_ord, '0') = '0' THEN '-0'  ELSE I.Qty_ord END) AS Qty_ord, 
    I.Item_no, I.Weight, 
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(I.Amount, '0') = '0' THEN '-0' ELSE I.Amount END) AS Amount, 
    I.Pkg_desc, I.Tax_amount, I.Ord_guide,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM dbo.InvoiceImportDataPrice IP 
     WHERE IP.Pkg_desc = V.VendorItemDescription
       AND IP.Item_no = V.VendorItemNumber 
       AND IP.Price = V.CurrentPrice) AS PriceDiscrepancyCount
FROM 
    dbo.InvoiceImportDataPrice  I
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.VendorItems V WITH (NOLOCK) ON V.VendorItemNumber = I.Ord_guide
WHERE 
    (I.InvoiceImportHistoryId = 128 AND VendorItemDescription != '"Sales Tax"') 
    or
    (I.InvoiceImportHistoryId = 128 AND ISNULL(V.VendorItemDescription, '') = '')
```

My problem is in 2 subqueries:

1.

```
    Id = (SELECT Min(k.Id) 
          FROM dbo.InvoiceImportDataPrice k 
          WHERE K.Ord_guide = I.Ord_guide 
            AND K.Price = I.Price
            AND k.Pkg_desc = I.Pkg_desc 
            AND k.Store_name = I.Store_name 
            AND k.InvoiceImportHistoryId = 128)
```

2.

```
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM dbo.InvoiceImportDataPrice IP 
     WHERE IP.Pkg_desc = V.VendorItemDescription
       AND IP.Item_no = V.VendorItemNumber 
       AND IP.Price = V.CurrentPrice) AS PriceDiscrepancyCount
```

Comment: manoj Index on tables may help you

Comment: Do you write code like that? Proper formatting makes things much easier.

Comment: i am not getting..

Comment: please post the execution plan of the above query,table schema,count of tables,so that one can check why it is slow ?

Comment: if i comment above these two queries then my execution time is very fast..but i need both query..so can you tell me how to do??

Comment: what is table schema??@TheGameiswar

Comment: You need to know way more than this.  Do you have a DBA?  First of course would be proper indexing, then stuff like execution plans, then fragmentation, etc.

Comment: try to change this from SELECT COUNT(*)  to SELECT COUNT(1) this * means all instead of 1

Comment: but i have also more then one value..

Comment: doesn't matter it returns a count too

Comment: this one change a join normally Id = (SELECT Min(k.Id) 
          FROM dbo.InvoiceImportDataPrice k 
          WHERE K.Ord_guide = I.Ord_guide 
            AND K.Price = I.Price
            AND k.Pkg_desc = I.Pkg_desc 
            AND k.Store_name = I.Store_name 
            AND k.InvoiceImportHistoryId = 128

Comment: it contains a lot of conditions..

Comment: good luck have to off now..

Comment: when i set count(1) then not effect in execution time @reds

Comment: Everyone's missing the issue that you've got subqueries within your select statement, this is never a good idea. check out my answer and see if changing them to joins helps at all.

Comment: @RichBenner your code taking too much time???

Comment: No, your code is taking too much time. We're just here to help. How long was it taking before? Have you seen any improvement by making the changes that I suggested? Some queries simply take some time based upon the data volume and your hardware configuration/software settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've formatted your code so that it's easier to read. Please provide the execution plan if you want more of an answer but on first glance there's a glaring issue that I see.

You have `subqueries` within your `SELECT` statement, these are more often than not a really bad idea. That's exactly what the `FROM` section is for. Move these statements as `subqueries` in joins rather than in the `SELECT` statement.

The reason that these will be poor for performance is that they will be executed once per row of your result set. If you add them in the join then they'll only be executed once (in total) which will allow SQL to do it as a set based approach.

You'll want something like this (untested as there is no sample data);

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ISNULL(V.VendorItemId, 0) AS VendorItemId,
    ISNULL(V.VendorItemNumber, I.Ord_guide) AS VendorItemNumber,
    ISNULL(V.VendorItemDescription, I.Pkg_desc) AS VendorItemDescription,
    Id = Sub1.MinID,
    I.InvoiceImportHistoryId, 
    I.Price,
    ISNULL(V.CurrentPrice, 0) AS CurrentPrice,
    ISNULL(ISNULL(V.CurrentPrice, 0) - ISNULL(I.Price, 0), 0) AS differencePrice,
    I.Invoice_No, 
    I.Sold_to, 
    I.Store_name, 
    I.Deliv_date,
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(I.Qty_ship, '0') = '0' THEN '-0' ELSE I.Qty_ship END) AS Qty_ship, 
    I.Ship_um, 
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(I.Qty_ord, '0') = '0' THEN '-0'  ELSE I.Qty_ord END) AS Qty_ord, 
    I.Item_no
    , I.Weight, 
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(I.Amount, '0') = '0' THEN '-0' ELSE I.Amount END) AS Amount
    ,I.Pkg_desc
    ,I.Tax_amount
    ,I.Ord_guide
    ,Sub2.Cnt AS PriceDiscrepancyCount
FROM 
    dbo.InvoiceImportDataPrice  I
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.VendorItems V WITH (NOLOCK) ON V.VendorItemNumber = I.Ord_guide
LEFT JOIN
        (
          SELECT Ord_Guide, Price, Pkg_desc, Store_name, Min(k.Id) MinID
          FROM dbo.InvoiceImportDataPrice k 
          WHERE k.InvoiceImportHistoryId = 128
          GROUP BY Ord_Guide, Price, Pkg_desc, Store_name
        ) Sub1
    ON Sub1.Ord_guide = I.Ord_guide 
    AND Sub1.Price = I.Price
    AND Sub1.Pkg_desc = I.Pkg_desc 
    AND Sub1.Store_name = I.Store_name 

LEFT JOIN 
        (
        SELECT Pkg_desc, Item_no, Price, COUNT(*) Cnt
        FROM dbo.InvoiceImportDataPrice IP 
        GROUP BY Pkg_desc, Item_no, Price
        ) Sub2
    ON Sub2.Pkg_desc = V.VendorItemDescription
    AND Sub2.Item_no = V.VendorItemNumber 
    AND Sub2.Price = V.CurrentPrice
WHERE 
    I.InvoiceImportHistoryId = 128 
    AND 
    (V.VendorItemDescription <> '"Sales Tax"' 
    OR
    V.VendorItemDescription IS NULL
    OR
    V.VendorItemDescription = '')
```

With regards to your formatting, it's better to follow best practices with regards to indentation etc. Ultimately there is a factor of personal preference but this should give you an idea of what you should be aiming for. Once you get used to this then debugging will be much easier for you;

[SQL Statement indentation good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272210/sql-statement-indentation-good-practice)

Comment: Sir it will taking almost 1 minute...but i want to do less then 10  second??what should i do???is there any changes needed??can you post the code in answer??

Comment: Then you need to read up on how to look at the execution plan for the query and see what's being slow. It may well be indexes or something similar but you'll need to check that Actual Execution Plan

Comment: I've just tweaked the WHERE clause because it wasn't SARGable, try that to see if it increases your performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two indexes on `InvoiceImportDataPrice`

non-clustered, non-unique, using indexed fields

```
Ord_guide
Price 
Pkg_desc
Store_name
Store_name
InvoiceImportHistoryId
```

AND

```
Item_no
Price
Pkg_desc
```